# Combine n sets of files together (randomly and no repetition)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge

I have the following sets of files:

Every file is discribed as follow `type-ID-pageNumber-R.xml` i.e jugement_017_3

**set 1:**

```
 - Conclusions-009-1-R.xml   
 - Conclusions-010-1-R.xml 
 - Conclusions-011-1-R.xml
```

**set 2:**

```
 - Assignation-043-1-R.xml    
 - Assignation-043-2-R.xml 
 - Assignation-045-1-R.xml
```

**set 3:**

```
 - Jugement-017-1-R.xml     
 - Jugement-017-2-R.xml  
 - Jugement-017-3-R.xml 
 - Jugement-018-1-R.xml 
 - Jugement-018-2-R.xml
```

---

I want to combine `set 1`, `set 2` and `set 3` into `set 4` by using the following rules:

1. Random order of combination (every time we want to combine the files, the order in set 4 will change)
2. Files of the same **type** can be placed one after the other **if** they have the same **ID**

---

**Set 4:**

```
- Conclusions-009-1-R.xml 
- Jugement-018-1-R.xml 
- Jugement-018-2-R.xml 
- Assignation-043-1-R.xml    
- Assignation-043-2-R.xml
- Conclusions-010-1-R.xml 
- Assignation-045-1-R.xml 
- Conclusions-011-1-R.xml
- Jugement-017-1-R.xml     
- Jugement-017-2-R.xml  
- Jugement-017-3-R.xml
```

---

Comment: just make the data structure more reflective of the semantics and shuffle the sources; pick one round robin to fill set 4. Make sure the 'linked' chapters are units in the source

Comment: Question Should I also shuffle the order of arrival of the files?
meaning: Even if shuffle them back at the source, i need to shuffle the order of sets too right?

Comment: You can. But then you need to somehow guard the invariants there

Comment: @sehe sorry can you be explain what do you mean by invariants. e

Comment: The constraints you list in the question.

Comment: oh, I assume you noticed my [elaboration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27808404/85371)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my $0.05 implementation to elaborate on my comment:

1. store all chapters inside a collection keyed by unique (section,chapter number):

   ```
   using Section = std::string;
   using Page    = int;
   using Chapter = int;
   using Pages   = icl::interval_set<Page>::type;

   struct Module {
       Section section;
       Chapter chapter;

       bool operator<(Module const& o) const;
   };

   using Table = std::map<Module, Pages>;
   ```

   As you can see I chose an interval set for storing the page ranges. This makes it easier to do the merging regardless of input order.
2. So let's do that. I fill the table in "random" order:

   ```
    struct Fill { Section s; Chapter c; Page p; };
    for (auto& fill : std::vector<Fill> { 
        { "Jugement",    18 , 2 },
        { "Conclusions", 11 , 1 },
        { "Assignation", 43 , 1 },
        { "Assignation", 43 , 2 },
        { "Conclusions", 10 , 1 },
        { "Jugement",    17 , 3 },
        { "Assignation", 45 , 1 },
        { "Jugement",    17 , 1 },
        { "Conclusions", 9  , 1 },
        { "Jugement",    17 , 2 },
        { "Jugement",    18 , 1 },
    })
    {
        table[{fill.s, fill.c}] += fill.p; // add page to (existing) range
    }
   ```

   That's all!
3. Now we can print the modules by section/chapter simply like this:

   ```
    std::cout << "------------- table: \n";
    for (auto& r:table)
        std::cout << r << "\n";
   ```

   Prints:

   ```
    ------------- table: 
    Assignation    43  {[1,2]}
    Assignation    45  {[1,1]}
    Conclusions    9   {[1,1]}
    Conclusions    10  {[1,1]}
    Conclusions    11  {[1,1]}
    Jugement   17  {[1,3]}
    Jugement   18  {[1,2]}
   ```
4. Now that we created the required *order*, let's add some *unpredictability* (which is subtly different from chaos).

   ```
   using rv = rw<Table::value_type>;
   std::vector<rv> vw(begin(table), end(table));

   // blind shuffle
   srand(time(0));
   std::random_shuffle(vw.begin(), vw.end());
   ```

   Bam. We have a shuffled view of references to the module table entries. **But!** Random is not the goal.

   So we find adjacent pairs from matching sections and try to remove those by rotating them away. It's possible, of course, that there will be nothing left to swap with (from another section) in which case we leave the duplicate(s) in the trailing position:

   ```
   // try to avoid subsequent modules from equal sections (dup)
   auto dup     = [](rv a, rv b) { return a.get().first.section == b.get().first.section; };
   auto it      = vw.begin();
   auto const e = vw.end();

   while(it != e) { // bit redundant, could be while(true)
       it = std::adjacent_find(it, e, dup);
       if (it == e) 
           break;

       auto m = std::find_if(it+1, e, [&] (rv r) { return r.get().first.section != it->get().first.section; });

       if (m == e) {
           it = m;
       } else {
           std::rotate(it+1, m, e);
           it = std::adjacent_find(it, e, dup);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Of course, print the resulting selection:

   ```
   std::cout << "------------- selection: \n";
   for (auto& r : vw)
       std::cout << r.get() << "\n";
   ```

A version that prints some diagnostic/trace information can be seen here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f01b2dce30e7de58)</kbd>**

[image]

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f01b2dce30e7de58)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

template<typename T> using rw = boost::reference_wrapper<T>;

using Section = std::string;
using Page    = int;
using Chapter = int;
using Pages   = icl::interval_set<Page>::type;

struct Module {
    Section section;
    Chapter chapter;

    bool operator<(Module const& o) const { return boost::tie(section,chapter) < boost::tie(o.section,o.chapter); }
};

using Table = std::map<Module, Pages>;

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Table::value_type const& p) {
    return os << p.first.section << "\t" << p.first.chapter << "\t" << p.second;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    Table table;

    {
        struct Fill { Section s; Chapter c; Page p; };
        for (auto& tup : std::vector<Fill> { 
            { "Jugement",    18 , 2 },
            { "Conclusions", 11 , 1 },
            { "Assignation", 43 , 1 },
            { "Assignation", 43 , 2 },
            { "Conclusions", 10 , 1 },
            { "Jugement",    17 , 3 },
            { "Assignation", 45 , 1 },
            { "Jugement",    17 , 1 },
            { "Conclusions", 9  , 1 },
            { "Jugement",    17 , 2 },
            { "Jugement",    18 , 1 },
        })
        {
            table[{tup.s, tup.c}] += tup.p; // add page to (existing) range
        }
    }

    std::cout << "------------- table: \n";
    for (auto& r:table)
        std::cout << r << "\n";

    {
        using rv = rw<Table::value_type>;
        std::vector<rv> vw(begin(table), end(table));

        // blind shuffle
        srand(time(0));
        std::random_shuffle(vw.begin(), vw.end());

        // try to avoid subsequent modules from equal sections (dup)
        auto dup     = [](rv a, rv b) { return a.get().first.section == b.get().first.section; };
        auto it      = vw.begin();
        auto const e = vw.end();

        while(it != e) // bit redundant, could be while(true)
        {
            std::cout << "------------- STATE: \n";
            for (auto& rv:vw)
                std::cout << rv.get() << (it->get_pointer() == rv.get_pointer()? "*\n":"\n");

            it = std::adjacent_find(it, e, dup);
            if (it == e) 
                break;

            std::cout << "------------- dupes: \n";
            std::cout << "\t" << (it+0)->get() << "\n";
            std::cout << "\t" << (it+1)->get() << "\n";

            auto m = std::find_if(it+1, e, [&] (rv r) { return r.get().first.section != it->get().first.section; });

            if (m == e)
            {
                it = m;
            } else
            {
                std::cout << "------------- rotating to: \n";
                std::cout << "\t" << m->get() << "\n";

                std::rotate(it+1, m, e);

                it = std::adjacent_find(it, e, dup);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "------------- selection: \n";
        for (auto& r : vw)
            std::cout << r.get() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand @sehe how the algorithm functions. I mean the technical part and it's really interesting. "using, "get_pointer()","get()" are new to me. The algorihm is simple but getting to understand it

Comment: You can use a vector of pointers if you prefer. I was lazy. **[See On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02a086193898273e)**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be reduced to a [well-known algorithm for random shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) if you could somehow eliminate your second requirement of consecutive placement of files with the same ID.

You can fix this by shuffling groups of files instead of individual files (of course a group may consist of a single file).

- Make a data structure that represents a file group with a specific type and ID, and a set of pages
- Combine your list of files into groups
- Run a random shuffle on a collection of groups
- Expand the results back into a list of individual files

Here is how this group structure might look:

```
class FileGroup {
    string name;
    string id;
    set<int> pages;
public:
    FileGroup(const string& _name, const string& _id) : name(_name), id(_id) {}
    void addPage(int pg) { pages.insert(pg); }
    ...
};
```

Your sample data would look like this:

```
"Assignation" - "043" - { 1, 2 }
"Assignation" - "045" - { 1 }
"Conclusions" - "009" - { 1 }
"Conclusions" - "010" - { 1 }
"Conclusions" - "011" - { 1 }
"Judgement"   - "017" - { 1, 2, 3 }
"Judgement"   - "018" - { 1, 2 }
```

Now the pages of related files would remain together, no matter what way you shuffle the groups.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I get this answer. Are you basically saying, "drop the requirements"? And then you suggest Fisher-Yates, while the standard library has `std::random_shuffle`. Anyhoops. I implemented what you sketched here (plus a heuristics best effort pass to remove adjacent modules from same sections)

Comment: @sehe The idea is to replace a list of objects that require different treatment (i.e. files that may be shuffled separately or be kept together) with objects that can be treated in a uniform way (i.e. file groups). In a way, this solution comes straight from [Dijkstra's railroad fable](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/ewd594.html). That's the same idea that you have implemented, too :)

Comment: I was aware of the fact that I implemented it :) Unless I'm missing something, that leaves the two remarks I made, right?